# adcash like site under pop up in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have seen adcash.com site under pop up/new page which is opened by every browser in new tab without any issues.i tried searching everywhere but could not find how to open a website in new tab without affecting the current webpage.

if you have used adcash.com site under script you might have noticed that when you click on next or any link one complete webpage will open in new tab and your present page will not at all affected.

plz help.i want to open ndtv.com in new tab not in new window but when users click on next page link that page should open there itself but ndtv.com should open in new tab.it means it has to work as usual and open next page in parent page plus new page in new tab.

Comment: there's no way to tell a browser how to open a new window, it's browser specific.  most modern browsers will open `target="_blank"` or `window.open()` in a new tab instead of a new window, but there's not a way to programmatically force this behavior in any browser.

Comment: have you tried anything

Comment: searched net lot but cant find anything

Comment: As Howard Renollet said, use`target="_blank"` on your link like this: `<a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">link</a>` on your link.

Comment: @JiFus plz stop kidding.if u will click users will go to google.com  but my question is open google.com in new tab and allow users to be at this page.when users click on next page link he should go to next page as well as new tab should open with google.com

Comment: I'm not kidding, if you think I am try it out. For me `<a target="_blank" href="google.com">Google</a>` opens google in a new tab. Or do you perhaps mean how to create a pop up ad, like: open a new tab, but still remain at the same page.

Comment: @JiFus what about next page link please read my comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what you said in the comments I think you are searching for something like this:

```
<a href="where-you-want-to-go.php" onclick="window.open('http://google.com');">Click</a>
```

What this will do is: Whenever you click "Click" it will go to where-you-want-to-go.php, and in the mean time it will open up google.com in a new tab.

Comment: What is not working? I tested in firefox, chrome, explorer and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Do two actions with one link.

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com" data-location="http://www.example.com">Google</a>

$("a").on("click", function () {
    window.location.href = $(this).data("location");
});
```

Comment: its not what i want.it opens  in new tab and redirects u to new tab  page but adcash ads keeps u in present page and ads are opened in new tab which you will see whenever you are closing tabs